# updating a software in Microsoft Store using cmd

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, windows-store-app, windows-store

I want to automate my Microsoft store Updates or Xbox software for pc updates (Microsoft Gaming App called Xbox). SO I want to know how to do that via a command in cmd so I can give it to task scheduler and make it happen.
Note: I almost know nothing about codes and cmd so explain it step by step please like I'm a 2-year-old child.

Comment: if it's simple enough to be done even a code in general. like a script or something!

Comment: Super User isn't a script writing service. You'll need to do some research, then show us where you're stuck. https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask